# Android Application Navigation

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I'm new to android programming and I need some help. Can anyone enlighten me about navigation(for example, Home, Contact Us). Do I need to use an intent? And how can I implement it on my activity_main.xml file as well as my MainActivity.java?

Comment: get start with with this http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: I know it's hard to understand how to develop an android application. it would be better you are searching for some tutorials and examples in www.

Comment: @dit yeah, its tough ): thanks though! (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like

```
Intent obj = new Intent(firstActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
startActivity(obj);
```

You must create res/layout/secondActivity.xml and /src/{package}/secondActivity.java and add something like

```
<activity android:name="secondActivity" android:label="@string/secondactivitylabel" ></activity>
```

in your AndroiManifest.xml

Comment: must i create more than 1 activity for every navigations i have?

Comment: Yup. You can consider an activity as a website page if you wish to. Your website can have all information in only one page or distribute it in many pages.

Comment: @user3774763 if you're satisfied, accept the question please